# ansible Ping test on raspberry pie

Tags: ansible, raspberry-pi

I am looking for an ansible module that can ping using the cellular interface,
and test the response.

I am running it on my raspberry pie as a verification for the cellular connection.

The equivalent to
`ping -I wwan0 google.com`

I couldn't find a module that does this in a simple way or do it at all.

Answer (score 0):

there is a `ping` module, but it does not take a source interface (`-I`) as a parameter. what about using the `command` module?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html

something simple like:

```
- name: Ping google.com from interface wwan0
  ansible.builtin.command: ping -I wwan0 google.com
```